# Problem in finding the element using the xPath using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to log-in the page and click the button which is located on top of the website but when i run code it says that element could not be found, below is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://go.xero.com/Dashboard")
user_name = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
user_name.send_keys("mnb@allied.ae")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys()
Submit = driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton")
Submit.click()
CS = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='xrh-appbutton--text']")
cs.click()

driver.quit()
```

---

below is the HTML source code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems it requires some time to find the elements. To manage this you need to implement wait mechanism in your scripts. Use either implicit or explicit waits. refer [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

**Implicit Wait**

```
driver.get("https://go.xero.com/Dashboard")
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

**Explicit Wait**

```
cs = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='xrh-appbutton--text']")))
cs.click()
```

Need to import following packages for this -

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thanks it sorted my issue